# How to make a Form stay on top of all other Forms for the entire application?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How to make a Form (It shows progress) stay on top of all other Forms in the entire application ONYL for my application forms?

Even on top of modal forms.
BUT, not on top of other desktop windows/application?

fsStayOnTop does not make the desired results.

Comment: "On top of modal forms" may cause usability issues.

Answer (score 1):

Use Win32 function SetWindowPos. Pass in HWND_TOP and a bunch of the  SWP_NO... values to leave all the attributes you do not want changed as they are.

I haven't tested this. Should be good though.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score -1):

You can try this simple trick:

```
procedure TProgressForm.FormDeactivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ProgressForm.BringToFront;
end;
```

Comment: Windows always appear above their owners. What's to keep this window on top of everything else?